# Is There a Way To Handle Files Locally Without Using php

Tags: php, html, file, web-applications

I'm  designing a web app (HTML/CSS/JS) that will run natively on my computer which I want to use to handle local files on my computer (like images and stuff like that.) I understand the use of php scripts and other browser security for a website running online, but is there an easier way to handle it if I'm running the application from my computer?

All I want to be able to do is browse my computer for files, "upload" those files to the web app (copy them into the relative path of the application), mess around and do various things with them, and then save them to a customizable path back onto my computer.

If there is not an easier way to do this, I would also accept suggestions about where to start with file management, I'm new to that area of web design.

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.electronjs.org/

Comment: Yes, Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) element with a type of file then you can manipulate the file using the [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/File) API.

If you need to have the paths of the files, you can use [Electron](https://electronjs.org) in conjunction with Node's [filesystem](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) API.